# How we can fail the testcase using Toleration threshold and Frustration threshold and how we display that result in summary report in Jmeter dashboard

Tags: automation, jmeter

How we can fail the test case using the Toleration threshold and Frustration threshold and how we display that result in a summary report in the Jmeter dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

1. `How we can fail the test case using the Toleration threshold and Frustration threshold` - as of [JMeter 5.4.3](https://lists.apache.org/thread/dbg1bxywcwx5vtdwqf8ownf7ppgqjn41) it's not possible to "fail" samplers based on the "thresholds"
2. Assuming point 1 all the results, even if they exceed the thresholds, will be marked as "passed" given the [status code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) is below 400

If you want JMeter to automatically fail the request if its response time exceeds acceptable threshold - consider adding [Duration Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Duration_Assertion) and set the maximum response time there, if the response time will be higher - JMeter will mark the relevant Sampler(s) as failed.

More information on JMeter Assertions concept: [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-three-easy-steps)